# How to turn off automatic restart of Tomcat in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

When developing Servlet, after changing a bit of my java code and clicking run, Eclipse asks me whether to restart the service or not. I clicked 'yes' and tick 'remember my choice'.

So every time, when I click 'run', the Tomcat will automatically restart.

Where can I turn off that feature? (in other words, I regret ticking the 'remember my choice')

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Eclipse - "Window" menu - Show View - Other - choose "servers" and ok button.

double click the server that you want to change settings in server view.

then server setting page will be opened.

you will see "Modules auto reload by default" option in Server options on the left bottom.

Comment: I always have trouble with this. Even though I deactivate it it keeps restarting the server. I use STS... Any ideas?