# How to turn ON automatic restart of Tomcat in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I want to setup Tomcat in Eclipse Luna to automatically restart, means opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712232/stop-eclipse-restarting-my-web-app-on-file-save) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682918/how-to-turn-off-automatic-restart-of-tomcat-in-eclipse)

When developing servlet, after changing my java code and then ran it Eclipse asked me to whether to restart the Tomcat or not. I clicked "no" and checked "remember my choice".

So every time, when I run servlet, the Tomcat will NOT automatically restart.

Where can I turn ON that feature (i.e., to clear "remember my choice" and set it opposite way).

I already tried opposite of what is advised in those two links but to no success. I tried both with "Modules auto reload by default" checked and unchecked.

**UPDATE**
I also tried to delete Tomcat several times and configure all over again, but it didn't help either. Here are available settings:

[image: Tomcat settings in Eclipse Luna]

Comment: I dont know the answer to this. But I guess you can always delete the current tomcat runtime in eclipse and create a new one. Then, it should give you that choice the first time again and you can choose wisely.

Comment: @MukulGoel I forgot to add that - the problem is that I DELETED Tomcat several times, but it keeps that option remembered.

Comment: Ahhh.. Sorry brother. I cant think of anything else. If its not too much hassle and having this really important. I would replace my eclipse with a new distribution.. hahah.. :D

Comment: @MukulGoel Honestly I started to think about it as well... This already took me too much time with no success :(

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand you right. Did  you try to replace eclipse with a fresh copy and it did not work?

Comment: @MukulGoel No, I haven't tried it yet, but as of your comment I am considering replacing Eclipse with fresh distribution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68506/discussion-between-mukul-goel-and-nenad-bulatovic).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you want to do is to update/modify launching preferences(how or when the server or runtime is launched).

To update launching preferences :

> Go to Window->Preferences->Server->Launching

Make the highlighted option to Always.

Source: [Defining the launching preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwlaunchpref.html)

[image]

Comment: Kudos! Nice & Easy :)